How to validate a dropdownmenu created with streamBuilder in a form
I am new to flutter and I am trying to validate a dropdownMenu. Like the other fields in the form I want the border to be red when the submit button is pressed
I am trying to validate using the controller. I know how to validate the other textfields with the form widget but I don't know how to do the same for the dropdownMenu
This is my code

class PaymentsForm extends StatefulWidget {
  const PaymentsForm({super.key});

  @override
  State<PaymentsForm> createState() => _PaymentsFormState();
}

class _PaymentsFormState extends State<PaymentsForm> {
  final _controller = TextEditingController();
  bool _isFieldEmpty = false;
  final GlobalKey<FormState> _paymentsFormKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  void _validateInput() {
    setState(() {
      print("Validating");
      _isFieldEmpty = _controller.text.isEmpty;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Dialog.fullscreen(
      child: Container(
        decoration: const BoxDecoration(color: primaryColor),
        // width: double.infinity,
        child: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            const Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(40, 40, 0, 80),
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  Gap(30),
                  CircleAvatar(
                    backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                    radius: 40,
                    child: Icon(
                      color: primaryColor,
                      Icons.credit_card,
                      size: 50,
                    ),
                  ),
                  Gap(20),
                  Text(
                    'Payments',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      letterSpacing: 3,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      color: Colors.white,
                      fontSize: 35,
                      fontFamily: customFont,
                    ),
                  ),
                  Gap(7),
                  Text(
                    'Make a payment',
                    style: TextStyle(
                        letterSpacing: 3,
                        fontFamily: customFont,
                        color: Colors.white,
                        fontSize: 15,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w100),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: Container(
                decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                      topRight: Radius.circular(10),
                      topLeft: Radius.circular(10)),
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),
                child: SingleChildScrollView(
                  child: Form(
                    key: _paymentsFormKey,
                    child: Column(
                      children: [
                        SizedBox(
                          height: 62,
                          width: double.infinity,
                          child: Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5),
                            child: SegmentedButton<String>(
                              style: SegmentedButton.styleFrom(
                                padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                                selectedForegroundColor: Colors.white,
                                selectedBackgroundColor: primaryColor,
                                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0),
                                  side: const BorderSide(
                                      color: Colors.black), // Add border
                                ),
                              ),
                              segments: const <ButtonSegment<String>>[
                                ButtonSegment<String>(
                                  value: 'KSH',
                                  label: Text('KSH'),
                                ),
                                ButtonSegment<String>(
                                  value: 'USD',
                                  label: Text('USD'),
                                ),
                                ButtonSegment<String>(
                                  value: 'USD/KSH',
                                  label: Text('USD/KSH'),
                                ),
                                ButtonSegment<String>(
                                  value: 'Expense',
                                  label: Text('Expense'),
                                ),
                              ],
                              selected: {transactionType},
                              onSelectionChanged: (Set<String> newSelection) {
                                setState(() {
                                  transactionType = newSelection.first;
                                });
                              },
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(5, 0, 5, 5),
                          child: SizedBox(
                            height: 45,
                            child: StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
                              stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
                                  .collection('users/$adeer/journal entries')
                                  .where("journalEntryType",
                                      isEqualTo: "Payment")
                                  .where("date",
                                      isGreaterThan: previousTimeStamp)
                                  .orderBy('date')
                                  .snapshots(),
                              builder: (BuildContext context,
                                  AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
                                if (snapshot.connectionState ==
                                    ConnectionState.waiting) {
                                  return TextField(
                                      decoration: kInputDecoration.copyWith(
                                          label: const Text(
                                              'Account from'))); // Placeholder for loading state
                                } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                                  return Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}');
                                } else {
                                  var accounts = snapshot.data!.docs;
                                  // print(
                                  //     'At j entry >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> $adeer >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>');

                                  List<DropdownMenuEntry<String>>
                                      dropdownEntries = accounts.map((account) {
                                    var firstName = account['first name'];
                                    var lastName = account['last name'];

                                    return DropdownMenuEntry<String>(
                                      value: '$firstName $lastName',
                                      label: '$firstName $lastName',
                                    );
                                  }).toList();
                                  // Return the DropdownMenu with the built entries

                                  return DropdownMenu(
                                    controller: _controller,
                                    expandedInsets: EdgeInsets.zero,
                                    requestFocusOnTap: true,
                                    label: const Text('Account from'),
                                    enableFilter: true,
                                    enableSearch: true,
                                    menuHeight: 200,
                                    inputDecorationTheme:
                                        dropdownDecoration.copyWith(
                                      border: OutlineInputBorder(
                                        borderSide: BorderSide(
                                          color: _isFieldEmpty
                                              ? Colors.red
                                              : Colors.grey,
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                    dropdownMenuEntries: dropdownEntries,
                                    onSelected: (String? value) {},
                                  );
                                }
                              },
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        Row(
                          children: [
                            Expanded(
                              flex: 2,
                              child: Padding(
                                padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(5, 0, 5, 5),
                                child: SizedBox(
                                  height: 45,
                                  child: TextFormField(
                                    inputFormatters: [
                                      LengthLimitingTextInputFormatter(
                                          32), // Limit the number of characters

                                      FilteringTextInputFormatter.deny(
                                          RegExp('[0-9]')),
                                    ],
                                    decoration: kInputDecoration.copyWith(
                                      errorStyle: TextStyle(height: 0),
                                      label: const Text('Receiver full name'),
                                    ),
                                    validator: (String? value) {
                                      if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
                                        return '';
                                      }
                                      receiver = value;
                                      return null;
                                    },
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                            Expanded(
                              child: Padding(
                                padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(
                                  0,
                                  0,
                                  5,
                                  5,
                                ),
                                child: SizedBox(
                                  height: 45,
                                  child: TextFormField(
                                    inputFormatters: [
                                      LengthLimitingTextInputFormatter(
                                          12), // Limit the number of characters
                                    ],
                                    decoration: kInputDecoration.copyWith(
                                        errorStyle: TextStyle(height: 0),
                                        label: const Text('Receiver \'s ID')),
                                    validator: (String? value) {
                                      if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
                                        return '';
                                      }
                                      receiver = value;
                                      return null;
                                    },
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                        if (transactionType == 'USD/KSH')
                          Row(
                            children: [
                              Expanded(
                                child: Padding(
                                  padding:
                                      const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(5, 3, 5, 5),
                                  child: SizedBox(
                                    height: 45,
                                    child: TextFormField(
                                      inputFormatters: [
                                        LengthLimitingTextInputFormatter(
                                            9), // Limit the number of characters

                                        FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(
                                            RegExp('[0-9]')),
                                      ],
                                      decoration: kInputDecoration.copyWith(
                                        errorStyle: TextStyle(height: 0),
                                        label: const Text('Dollar amount'),
                                      ),
                                      validator: (String? value) {
                                        if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
                                          return '';
                                        }
                                        receiver = value;
                                        return null;
                                      },
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                              Expanded(
                                child: Padding(
                                  padding:
                                      const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 3, 5, 5),
                                  child: SizedBox(
                                    height: 45,
                                    child: TextFormField(
                                      inputFormatters: [
                                        LengthLimitingTextInputFormatter(
                                            9), // Limit the number of characters

                                        FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(
                                            RegExp('[0-9]')),
                                      ],
                                      decoration: kInputDecoration.copyWith(
                                        errorStyle: TextStyle(height: 0),
                                        label: const Text('Ksh amount'),
                                      ),
                                      validator: (String? value) {
                                        if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
                                          return '';
                                        }
                                        receiver = value;
                                        return null;
                                      },
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        if (transactionType == 'USD')
                          Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(5, 3, 5, 5),
                            child: SizedBox(
                              height: 45,
                              child: TextFormField(
                                inputFormatters: [
                                  LengthLimitingTextInputFormatter(
                                      9), // Limit the number of characters

                                  FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(
                                      RegExp('[0-9]')),
                                ],
                                decoration: kInputDecoration.copyWith(
                                  errorStyle: TextStyle(height: 0),
                                  label: const Text('Dollar amount'),
                                ),
                                validator: (String? value) {
                                  if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
                                    return '';
                                  }
                                  receiver = value;
                                  return null;
                                },
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        if (transactionType == 'KSH')
                          Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(5, 3, 5, 5),
                            child: SizedBox(
                              height: 45,
                              child: TextFormField(
                                inputFormatters: [
                                  LengthLimitingTextInputFormatter(
                                      9), // Limit the number of characters

                                  FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(
                                      RegExp('[0-9]')),
                                ],
                                decoration: kInputDecoration.copyWith(
                                  errorStyle: TextStyle(height: 0),
                                  label: const Text('Ksh amount'),
                                ),
                                validator: (String? value) {
                                  if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
                                    return '';
                                  }
                                  receiver = value;
                                  return null;
                                },
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        if (transactionType == "Expense")
                          Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(5, 3, 5, 5),
                            child: SizedBox(
                              height: 45,
                              child: TextFormField(
                                inputFormatters: [
                                  LengthLimitingTextInputFormatter(
                                      9), // Limit the number of characters

                                  FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(
                                      RegExp('[0-9]')),
                                ],
                                decoration: kInputDecoration.copyWith(
                                  errorStyle: TextStyle(height: 0),
                                  label: const Text('Expense amount'),
                                ),
                                validator: (String? value) {
                                  if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
                                    return '';
                                  }
                                  receiver = value;
                                  return null;
                                },
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(5, 3, 5, 10),
                          child: TextFormField(
                            maxLines: 3,
                            minLines: 1,
                            inputFormatters: [
                              LengthLimitingTextInputFormatter(
                                  50), // Limit the number of characters
                            ],
                            decoration: kInputDecoration.copyWith(
                              errorStyle: TextStyle(height: 0),
                              label: const Text('Remarks'),
                            ),
                            validator: (String? value) {
                              if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
                                return '';
                              }
                              receiver = value;
                              return null;
                            },
                          ),
                        ),
                        Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
                          child: Row(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                            children: [
                              SizedBox(
                                width: 130,
                                height: 40,
                                child: ElevatedButton(
                                  style: const ButtonStyle(
                                    foregroundColor:
                                        WidgetStatePropertyAll<Color>(
                                            Colors.white),
                                    backgroundColor:
                                        WidgetStatePropertyAll<Color>(
                                            secondaryColor),
                                  ),
                                  onPressed: () {
                                    Navigator.of(context).pop();
                                  },
                                  child: const Text('Cancel'),
                                ),
                              ),
                              const Gap(10),
                              SizedBox(
                                width: 130,
                                height: 40,
                                child: ElevatedButton(
                                  style: const ButtonStyle(
                                    foregroundColor:
                                        WidgetStatePropertyAll<Color>(
                                            Colors.white),
                                    backgroundColor:
                                        WidgetStatePropertyAll<Color>(
                                            primaryColor),
                                  ),
                                  onPressed: () {
                                    _validateInput();
                                    print(_isFieldEmpty);
                                    if (_paymentsFormKey.currentState!
                                        .validate()) {
                                      showDialog<String>(
                                        context: context,
                                        builder: (BuildContext context) =>
                                            AlertDialog(
                                          title: const Text('Confirm payment'),
                                          content: Text(
                                              'Make a payment of$receiver'),
                                          actions: <Widget>[
                                            TextButton(
                                              onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(
                                                  context, 'Cancel'),
                                              child: const Text('Cancel'),
                                            ),
                                            TextButton(
                                              onPressed: () {
                                                _paymentsFormKey.currentState
                                                    ?.reset();
                                                Navigator.pop(context, 'OK');
                                              },
                                              child: const Text('OK'),
                                            ),
                                          ],
                                        ),
                                      );
                                    }
                                  },
                                  child: const Text('Submit'),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}


This is the dropdownMenu
StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
                              stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
                                  .collection('users/$adeer/journal entries')
                                  .where("journalEntryType",
                                      isEqualTo: "Payment")
                                  .where("date",
                                      isGreaterThan: previousTimeStamp)
                                  .orderBy('date')
                                  .snapshots(),
                              builder: (BuildContext context,
                                  AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
                                if (snapshot.connectionState ==
                                    ConnectionState.waiting) {
                                  return TextField(
                                      decoration: kInputDecoration.copyWith(
                                          label: const Text(
                                              'Account from'))); // Placeholder for loading state
                                } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                                  return Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}');
                                } else {
                                  var accounts = snapshot.data!.docs;
                                  // print(
                                  //     'At j entry >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> $adeer >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>');

                                  List<DropdownMenuEntry<String>>
                                      dropdownEntries = accounts.map((account) {
                                    var firstName = account['first name'];
                                    var lastName = account['last name'];

                                    return DropdownMenuEntry<String>(
                                      value: '$firstName $lastName',
                                      label: '$firstName $lastName',
                                    );
                                  }).toList();
                                  // Return the DropdownMenu with the built entries

                                  return DropdownMenu(
                                    controller: _controller,
                                    expandedInsets: EdgeInsets.zero,
                                    requestFocusOnTap: true,
                                    label: const Text('Account from'),
                                    enableFilter: true,
                                    enableSearch: true,
                                    menuHeight: 200,
                                    inputDecorationTheme:
                                        dropdownDecoration.copyWith(
                                      border: OutlineInputBorder(
                                        borderSide: BorderSide(
                                          color: _isFieldEmpty
                                              ? Colors.red
                                              : Colors.grey,
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                    dropdownMenuEntries: dropdownEntries,
                                    onSelected: (String? value) {},
                                  );
                                }
                              },
                            ),

